# RabbitMQ and node-amqp: Exchange in confirmed mode does not confirm - why?

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq, node-amqp

I am writing a Node.js application that relies on RabbitMQ. I'm using node-amqp as the library of choice to connect to RabbitMQ.

Once I have established a connection to RabbitMQ, first thing I am going to do is to create an exchange:

```
var options = { autoDelete: false, confirm: true, durable: true, type: 'direct' };
connection.exchange('myExchange', options, function (myExchange) {
  // ...
});
```

This works perfectly. As you can see, I am creating the exchange using `confirm: true`, hence I expect the exchange to be in confirm mode afterwards.

Now a problem appears once I try to publish a message:

```
var options = {};
myExchange.publish('', { data: 'foobar' }, options, function () {
  // ...
});
```

The problem is that the callback of the `publish` function is never called - although the message was successfully published (as I can see within RabbitMQ's web management tool).

Did I understand confirm mode in a wrong way? Is this a bug with node-amqp?

Any help would be appreciated :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Question answered in the appropriate [GitHub issue](https://github.com/postwait/node-amqp/issues/134): node-amqp on npm is an old version ... current workaround is to use the `master` branch from GitHub directly.

This means, use `https://github.com/postwait/node-amqp/tarball/master` when installing using `npm`.

---

**Update November 2013**

As I was using RabbitMQ again these days (about one year after my original question), I thought it might be a good idea to give an update on the status quo of node-amqp.

Unfortunately the state of node-amqp is exactly the same as a year ago: The published version from npm is hardly usable. Some of the bugs I encountered a year ago are still there (including the one from my question), so the given workaround is still valid: Get the latest master from GitHub.

Comment: this appears to be fixed in node-amqp version 0.2.0.  The published npm version works for me.